# Looking for a WinForms .Net Folder/File browser UI control for accessing WebDAV and SharePoint folders

Tags: winforms, sharepoint, controls, webdav, folderbrowserdialog

I have a need to be able to browse and access WebDAV and SharePoint folders in a WinForms app.

I am aware of the following .Net libraries for accessing WebDAV folders. From what I can tell these do not appear to include any ready to use WinForms UI controls and would require building one's own utilizing their client libraries:

http://www.independentsoft.de/webdav/index.html
http://www.webdavsystem.com/client
http://www.eldos.com/sbb/desc-webdav.php

I have found the ShellMegaPack FolderView and FileView controls, which appear to generally work (more testing is required):

http://www.ssware.com/megapack.htm

I would like to know if there are any other folder/file browser UI controls out there that I could evaluate.

Thanks, Elan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find any control that satisfied my needs. I ended up writing my own. Windows 7 and .Net 4.0 provide built-in support for accessing SharePoint and WebDAV folders using the standard System.IO library.

If a web folder requires authentication and authentication was done earlier in Windows  Explorer, then no additional authentication is required using the System.IO classes. I have also been able to show the Windows login prompt dialog for authentication using the Windows Shell APIs through interop.

**Update:**

The above works on both Windows 7 and Windows XP using standard System.IO classes with UNC path to the web folder. The only limitation I see on XP is that it does not support custom port numbers in the UNC path, whereas on Windows 7 one can use custom port numbers.